# Does exposure to verbal abuse increases emotional stability?

Tags: emotion

At my university, many students have to go through a form of hazing for a period of a one month in the second years of their undergraduate studies. A part of it consists of a session where the students get shouted at by their seniors. According to them, this exposure to pressure "opens" them up and increases their emotional stability in the long run. They back up their claims by a lot of anecdotal evidence. I have a hunch that this is not true. What does research in psychology say about the long-term implications of such methods?

Comment: This refers to things in the military where commanding officers shout insults and not from parents to children right?